# Having problems trying to output blog post data using jinja

Tags: python, html, jinja2

So I have this dummy json file which has id, title, subtitle, and post, using npoint here's the link to json data: https://api.npoint.io/5abcca6f4e39b4955965, and what i'm trying to do was display the title and subtitle of the 3 posts from the dummy json file. I used jinja multi line to loop through the post within the html. But I keep getting an error, I've tried printing out the data to console and it worked just fine.

here's my server.py :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template #grabs your html page to render
import random
import requests
from datetime import datetime
 
app = Flask(__name__)
 
 
 
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "<h1> Welcome! </h1>"
 
@app.route('/blog')
def blog():
    blog_url = "https://api.npoint.io/5abcca6f4e39b4955965"
    response = requests.get(url=blog_url)
    data = response.json()
    return render_template("blog.html", posts=data)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and heres my blog.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for blog_posts in posts: %}
            <h1>{{ blog_posts["title] }}</h1>
            <h2>{{ blog_posts["subtitle"] }}</h2>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Error :

```
File "C:\Users\Vimalan\PycharmProjects\100CODECHALLENGE\Webdev\Blog\templates\blog.html", line 10, in template

<h2>{{ blog_posts["subtitle"] }}</h2>
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'subtitle'
```

any suggestions?

Comment: you are missing `"` here blog_posts["title`"`]

Comment: oh my god... thank you!! I need to get my eyes checked...